# Pandoc on Microsoft Azure gives getAppUserDataDirectory error

Tags: azure, pandoc

I am trying to run Pandoc on MS Azure environment to create HTML report from markdown file. The Pandoc command is real simple one.

> pandoc test.md -o test.html

But I get the following error.

> pandoc: getAppUserDataDirectory:sHGetFolderPath: illegal operation (unsupported operation)

It seems to me that MS Azure has Windows 10 sort of environment. I even tried to set up `XDG_DATA_HOME` or `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, but it still gives the same error.

Can you someone please help?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3241) GitHub issue talks about a similar issue.  The explanation for the message is as follows: "Some more info: For this specific case the getAppUserDataDirectory does not mean the the User does not have a directory, it is just mean that the Haskel functions and subsequently the win32 libraries that Haskell uses cannot 'find' that directory. This is happening, because the user that run the R Script (thus calling the pandoc.exe) is not a 'real' user."  *What that tells me is the user attempting to perform the work doesn't have access to the file.*

Comment: @Ramhound, I looked into the link. I am just running Windows batch file with a pandoc command. I am not sure why it is not able to "see/find" getAppUserDataDirectory.

Comment: To be clear, `getAppUserDataDirectory` is a method within Pandoc, so if it's not working then it's probably an environmental variable issue.

Comment: Yes. Agree. But how to setup this directory in some way?

Comment: Have you set [`--data-dir=DIR`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7486) to the directory that contains the files?  What is the contents of `~/.local/share/pandoc/defaults`?  The final command would indeed be `test.md -o test.html --data-dir=testdir`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the comments. I was able to solve this issue with using `--data-dir` flag in my call. Here is what I used.

> pandoc test.md -o test.pdf --data-dir=.

(**Note** `.` means current directory).

Thanks.